# How to authenticate with AWS API to launch a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to create Java REST API(not with SDK) to launch a AWS EC2 instance.

First of all I need to Authenticate with the AWS API server by using Signature and Accesskey. I tried using the [AWS documentations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RequestAuthenticationArticle.html) but I am facing the below error.

```
<Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message>
```

Could someone suggest me the steps to implement authentication with API and launching the instance in AWS. Also share if any existing GitHub code for the above requirement.

Comment: So your requirement is to implement a REST API to start a EC2 instance? Have you look at API Gateway Lambda, which is much cheaper alternative to implement this without paying for a EC2 instance. Also when you say not with SDK what do you mean by that?

Comment: The documentation link you cited is for the amazon.com Product Advertising API... not EC2.  EC2 docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html#query-authentication

Answer (score 0):

You have to use,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html

There are ways you can gain access.
Create Access Key and Secret with IAM and pass them to java client.

Or you can create a role for an EC2 instance and assign the role to your Ec2 instance. Any code run from that EC2 instance will have access to the role mentioned.

Either with IAM Access Key or EC2 Instance Role, you need to have EC2 Policy with EC2FullAccess to access the API.